# ExtJS: How to hide displayfields if binded data is empty

Tags: extjs, extjs6

The panel has many fields that should not be displayed when data is empty.

```
{
    xtype: 'displayfield',
    fieldLabel: 'Date begin',
    bind: {
        value: '{record.date_begin}'
    }
}
```

Is there a good practice to hide **displayfields** if binded data is empty?

Comment: Yes, did you try `hidden: '{!record.date_begin}'`?

Answer (score 2):

To be able to hide the best way is to bind, as below you can keep the bind by value and also add the bind by hidden, when the value is filled it will make the field visible.

```
{
    xtype: 'displayfield',
    fieldLabel: 'Date begin',
    bind: {
        value: '{record.date_begin}',
        hidden: '{record.date_begin === false || record.date_begin == null}'
    }
}
```

EDIT:
To work when the value is 0.

Comment: Please add some coments to your answer

Comment: This won't work in all cases, for example if it has a value of `0`.

Comment: This was already answered in the comment's section of the question.

Comment: Right, but your initial edit was exactly that answer. And by the way, empty data is not the same as the data containing the value 0.

Comment: Note that the framework added the conditional logic in bindings in 6.2.x+, so the above would have to be turned into an actual VM formula if you wanted to leverage this answer for previous versions.